# Scale prices in multiple stocks for comparison

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, finance

I have a chart with prices of multiple stocks.

The problem is that some prices are below 100 while others are above 1000, so the chart is really ugly.

How do I compare historical in multiple stocks, so the chart is still readable. For instace, if I add Berkshire Hathaway, I won't be able to read anything off my chart because of the large gap between prices of different stocks.

I wonder if that's what the logarithmic scale is for?

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the idea behind having one axis using a logarithmic scale. It is always a good idea to use this if the data varies over more than an order of magnitude.

Comment: But it doesn't change much. Should I use a base different from $10$ or $e$?

Comment: I think maybe you're not doing the log scale properly. If you have prices under \$100, then they will have values between 1 and 2 on the log scale. Prices over \$1000 will have a value something over 3, only going over 4 if the price is over \$10000. This seems very unlikely.